# How to detect collision between UIImageViews?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm building a game, in which I want to detect collision between UIImageViews, I am adding all the UIImageViews in an array and there is another image of a ball which is bouncing around the screen. I'm not able to detect the collision between those UIImageViews I added in the array(self.myViews) and the UIImageView of the ball I added in the Storyboard. I can't figure out the problem.

```
- (void) performAnimation {

int widht;
int heigh;

for (UIView * obj in self.myViews){
    [obj removeFromSuperview];
}



[self.myViews addObject:self.Ball];
[self.view addSubview: self.Ball];


for (heigh = 30; heigh < 200; heigh = heigh + 40) {

    for (widht = 35; widht < 300; widht = widht + 40) {


        UIImageView *image0 =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(widht,heigh,20,10)];
        image0.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"gruener-balken.png"];


        [self.view addSubview:image0];
        [self.myViews addObject:image0];

    }

   }
}

- (void)BallMovement {

for (UIImageView *obj in self.myViews) {

    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(obj.frame, _Ball.frame)) {

        //something happens here

    }

}
}
```

I want to create the UIImageViews dynamically and add them to a mutable array (myViews). Then I want to detect the collision between those UIImageViews in the array and the ImageView I created in the storyboard (_Ball.frame). The problem is, that no collision is detected, and the ball moves behind the image views from the loop.

Comment: And you have checked that your code is called? And logged the frames?

Comment: Where is that detection code? Cocoa apps don't have a *tick()* method that is run every frame, so you would need to run it within a timer-driven method...

Comment: Apple introduced UICollisionBehavior in iOS 7. Take a look on this catalog https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/DynamicsCatalog/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: The second loop is called, but a breakpoint at the if statement has no effect. But I have no idea why.

Comment: I'm also not sure why you need `self.myViews` given you can just enumerate the subviews of `self.view`.  Also the code that does `removeFromSubview` near the top doesn't remove views from `self.myViews` and lastly there *should* always be a collision as it will compare `self.Ball` with `self.Ball`...

Comment: The collision detecting loop is called by a timer every 0.01 seconds.

Comment: I think the main problem is, that the if statement isn'n called, but I really don't understand why.

Comment: is `self.myViews` being created somewhere? put some `NSLog(@"myViews: %@",self.myViews);` before the for loop in `BallMovement` to see if everything is fine with it.